Why would the person who led the police to Luigi Mangione be eligible for a reward from the FBI?
According to this news article, the FBI offered a $50,000 reward for any information leading to an arrest and conviction for the murder of Brian Thompson that would be paid out through the State Department's "Rewards for Justice" program.
But the program's website says that it only applies to four categories of activity that is harmful to national security:

International terrorism or the financing of foreign terrorist organizations,
Foreign interference in domestic elections,
Malicious cyber activity, or
Supporting the North Korean regime.

I don't see how the murder of Brian Thompson could possibly fall into any of these categories. It might conceivably be considered an act of domestic terrorism, but certainly not international terrorism. So how was the FBI legally authorized to offer a reward as part of this investigation?

Are you sure that only those four categories are valid? From your link: Since 1984, Congress has **expanded** the RFJ’s statutory authorities [...] (emphasis mine). It could be interpreted that the four categories have been added after the creation of the program in 1984. Take into account that your link is from the Departament of State, that focus on foreign issues, so maybe they are only highlighting the parts that affect to them the most.

Nothing about that article, which is pretty light on facts (as nobody ever suggested not issuing the reward) suggests that the reward must come from the Rewards for Justice program -- they just said that they took some info about the procedure for issuing a reward from that site.  It's even unclear whether the procedure holds for rewards outside of this program.  It's a pretty bad article.

@SJuan76 According to https://rewardsforjustice.net/about/frequently-asked-questions/, the program originally only covered international terrorism, and then in 2017 Congress added in cyber crimes and North Korea. The site in my OP says that Congress has expanded the program's scope to the four categories listed in my OP, not from those four.
